# Background for positive mass theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

Given a solid background in Riemannian geometry and classical differential geometry but no prior experience with general relativity, what would be good textbooks and/or articles to build a foundation for the understanding of the positive mass theorem?

Comment: Some elliptic PDE theory is essential. You could try looking at Dan Lee's book, Geometric Relativity and see what he says about prerequisites.

Comment: The positive-mass theorem doesn't require much of a physics background unless you want to understand where the motivation behind defining the mass contained by a spatial slice of a given spacetime comes from. So I'd rather focus on the math requirements, namely minimal-surface theory (this includes some elliptic PDE theory) and, especially for the n-dimensional proof, a good foundation in geometric measure theory.